# Hide a child window from parent window hide all app

Tags: cocoa

I have 2 windows one is the header [mainWindow] (`-setMovableByWindowBackground:YES`) and the other is the content [secWindow], child of the header, the header have a button to hide the content.

```
[mainWindow addChildWindow:secWindow ordered:NSWindowBelow];
[mainWindow setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
```

code to hide secWindow:

```
(IBAction) toggleSecondary: (id) sender;
{
if ([secWindow isVisible]) {
    [secWindow orderOut:self];
} else {        
    [secWindow orderFront:self];
}
}
```

The problem is when a push the button, all app hide, Main and Sec windows and only need to hide the [secWindow].

Answer (score 4):

Weel, I found a solution, I don't know if a correct way, but works for me. ^_^

```
//get the mainWindow cordinates
NSRect theFrame = [mainWindow frame];
NSPoint theOrigin = theFrame.origin;
NSPoint pSecWin = theFrame.origin;
//put secWin below mainWindow
pSecWin.y = theOrigin.y - secHeight;

(IBAction) toggleSecondary: (id) sender;
{
if ([secWindow isVisible]) {
    [mainWindow removeChildWindow:secWindow];
    [secWindow orderOut:self];
} else {  
    [secWindow setFrameOrigin:pSecWin];
    [mainWindow addChildWindow:secWindow ordered:NSWindowBelow];      
    [secWindow orderFront:self];
}
}
```

so thats it, thanks anyway

Comment: This helped me, thanks! On Snow Leopard, when I was ordering out the child window before removing it the parent window would also get hidden - removing the child from the parent before ordering out fixed it. Didn't see the same issue on Lion however.

Comment: thanks. Looks like SDK shall provide a simple way to hide and show a child NSWindow.. I could't find it.. Your code works.